# How to create a dual action (normal + switch) preference in Android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

Is there any way to achieve this dual-action preference item?  Preferably via a third party library but via a simple implementation if necessary.

The 'wireless debugging' preference in Android's developer mode is a dual preference. It's the only one I've seen and I have no idea what this preference is called or if any Jetpack or other libraries expose such a thing.

Tapping the left part (1) opens a new screen, while tapping the right toggle (2) simply toggles the preference without changing screens. There's also a little divider between them to indicate that they have separate actions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found a way to do this, and it works for older versions of Android too. [See here](https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger/blob/master/gpslogger/src/main/java/com/mendhak/gpslogger/ui/components/SwitchPlusClickPreference.java).  I'll paste the code at the end of this post.

Here's what it looks like, the two zones are shown. Pressing the toggle just toggles the toggle (lol) and pressing the left part invokes a method, in which you can launch an activity.

I couldn't figure out how to draw a vertical bar between them.

[image: switch plus preference]

How I use it.

The settings xml:

```xml
<com.mendhak.gpslogger.ui.components.SwitchPlusClickPreference
        android:key="my_pref"
        android:summary="my summary"
        android:title="my title" />
```

And in the activity's code, I have to handle both the events.

```java
((SwitchPlusClickPreference)findPreference("my_pref"))
                .setSwitchClickListener(new SwitchPlusClickPreference.SwitchPlusClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(SwitchCompat buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // No need to do anything, the value gets propagated.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Do something like launch another activity
                    }
                });
```

Finally the code for `SwitchPlusClickPreference`

```java
package com.mendhak.gpslogger.ui.components;


import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceViewHolder;
import androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat;

// Originally from: https://gist.github.com/marchold/45e22839eb94aa14dfb5
// Modified to work with SwitchPreferenceCompat

/**
 * Custom preference for handling a switch with a clickable preference area as well
 */
public class SwitchPlusClickPreference extends SwitchPreferenceCompat {

    //
    // Public interface
    //

    /**
     * Sets listeners for the switch and the background container preference view cell
     * @param listener A valid SwitchPlusClickListener
     */
    public void setSwitchClickListener(SwitchPlusClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    private SwitchPlusClickListener listener = null;

    /**
     * Interface gives callbacks in to both parts of the preference
     */
    public interface SwitchPlusClickListener {
        /**
         * Called when the switch is switched
         * @param buttonView
         * @param isChecked
         */
        public void onCheckedChanged(SwitchCompat buttonView, boolean isChecked);

        /**
         * Called when the preference view is clicked
         * @param view
         */
        public void onClick(View view);
    }

    public SwitchPlusClickPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public SwitchPlusClickPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SwitchPlusClickPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    //
    // Internal Functions
    //

    /**
     * Recursively go through view tree until we find an android.widget.Switch
     * @param view Root view to start searching
     * @return A Switch class or null
     */
    private SwitchCompat findSwitchWidget(View view){
        if (view instanceof  SwitchCompat){
            return (SwitchCompat)view;
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup){
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount();i++){
                View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
                if (child instanceof ViewGroup){
                    SwitchCompat result = findSwitchWidget(child);
                    if (result!=null) return result;
                }
                if (child instanceof SwitchCompat){
                    return (SwitchCompat)child;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        final SwitchCompat switchView = findSwitchWidget(holder.itemView);
        if (switchView!=null){
            switchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null)
                        listener.onCheckedChanged((SwitchCompat) v, ((SwitchCompat)v).isChecked());
                }
            });
            switchView.setChecked(getSharedPreferences().getBoolean(getKey(),false));
            switchView.setFocusable(true);
            switchView.setEnabled(true);
            //Set the thumb drawable here if you need to. Seems like this code makes it not respect thumb_drawable in the xml.
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener!=null) listener.onClick(v);
            }
        });
    }

//    //Get a handle on the 2 parts of the switch preference and assign handlers to them
//    @Override
//    protected void onBindView (View view){
//        super.onBindView(view);
//
//        final Switch switchView = findSwitchWidget(view);
//        if (switchView!=null){
//            switchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(View v) {
//                    if (listener != null)
//                        listener.onCheckedChanged((Switch) v, ((Switch)v).isChecked());
//                }
//            });
//            switchView.setChecked(getSharedPreferences().getBoolean(getKey(),false));
//            switchView.setFocusable(true);
//            switchView.setEnabled(true);
//            //Set the thumb drawable here if you need to. Seems like this code makes it not respect thumb_drawable in the xml.
//        }
//
//        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                if (listener!=null) listener.onClick(v);
//            }
//        });
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well There is an element in AndroidStudio Call Switch which is similar to this use that in XML file

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting - they've created an `android.widget.Switch` but it seems nothing for preference screens. I wonder if I'd have to create a custom preference that wraps a `Switch` somehow.